# PHP SESSION from jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, session, .post

I have read plenty of articles, both here and elsewhere, regarding this issue without finding an answer that could help me. And since the subject seem to be rather broad, I presume the best way is to ask.

I am currently sending login-data from a form to a php-script through a $.post-script in a jquery-file. No problems there. I have a class that walks through a chain of function to validate and secure the strings, so no issue at all. I get all the way to setting the session, which I can print out and get by adding function(data) to my $.post.

I have added session_start() to both the php-script and to the index.php. I'm using Chromium and can see that a session has been set, but when I make a print_r($_SESSION); it comes out empty. Which also, evidently, leads to my if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])) won't work either.

js:

```
$('#login').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    values = {};
    var url = '../admin/php/signIn.php';
    console.log('Clicked on submit.');
    $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, field){
        values[field.name] = field.value;
    });
    $.post(url, {username: values.username, password: values.password})
    .done(function(data){ location.reload(); /*alert(data);*/ })
    .fail(function(){ alert('Fail.'); });
});
```

php:

```
private function login($uid, $uname){
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
    echo $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
    session_start();
}
```

I added an echo on one of the sessions, just to be able to see it through jquery.
Is the issue with "private function [...]", or elsewhere? (Playing with classes, as I said before.)

I hope this makes sense to someone, since I am rather lost here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call `session_start()` **before** you start assigning variable sessions.

Comment: And do I feel stupid? I have worked a lot with this before, but I presume it's one of those evenings. Thank you, it worked.

Comment: @RichardAtterfalk When that happens, it's a good time to take a nap lol

Comment: True! After all, it's past midnight. But now the login-script is complete and I can continue styling and adding CRUD. But that's for tomorrow. Once again, thanks for the help. :)